# How do I find out where a message is being sent from?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Our app is crashing during our tests, sending a message to a deallocated `UINavigationItem`.  I've looked using Instruments, but all the releases and retains look balanced; it looks like something is hanging onto the variable without retaining it.  I'd like to find where the message is being sent from, so that I can make sure that the object stays alive long enough to receive it.

The error in the console is:

```
-[UINavigationItem safeValueForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x11afab80
```

The stack trace is:

```
 0 CoreFoundation ___forwarding___
 1 CoreFoundation _CF_forwarding_prep_0
 2 UIKit -[UINavigationItemButtonViewAccessibility(SafeCategory) accessibilityTraits]
 3 UIAccessibility -[NSObject(NSObjectAccessibility) accessibilityAttributeValue:]
 4 UIAccessibility _copyAttributeValueCallback
 5 AXRuntime _AXXMIGCopyAttributeValue
 6 AXRuntime _XCopyAttributeValue
 7 AXRuntime mshMIGPerform
 8 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
 9 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSource1
10 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
11 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
12 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
13 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal
14 GraphicsServices GSEventRun
15 UIKit UIApplicationMain
16 MyApp Functional Tests main [myapp]/main.m:14
17 MyApp Functional Tests start
```

...but none of that is in my code.  How do I find out where the message is being sent from?

Comment: which Instruments have you tried so far?  Leaks?  Have you turned on Zombies?

Comment: `grep` your sources for `item = [UINavigationItem alloc] ...`, most likely you'll have to simply use `self.item` to have it retained. The @property could be wrong, too.

Comment: no such luck, I'm afraid - the UINavigationItem in question is being created by the UINavigationController at the root of my view hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Command:

Shell malloc_history process_id memory

eg. Shell malloc_history process_id 0x11afab80

Enable Following for the same
1)MallocstackLogging
2) NsDebugEnabled
3)NSZombieEnabled

this will solve the problem

Comment: +1 thought it will not solve the problem, it will highlight the problem part :)